# How to debug through a karate testing project using Maven?

Tags: maven-3, karate, nashorn

Is there a way I can debug through the test in a similar way that I would debug a Java app using Maven?
For example, if I set breakpoint in the implementstion of step and click on debug with next parameters of CL:
`mvn clean test -Dkarate.options="--tags ~@ignore" -Dtest=MainRunner -DforkCount=0`

and I'm getting next errors:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ karateSberApi ---
[WARNING] useSystemClassloader setting has no effect when not forking
[INFO] Running examples.MainRunner
before all
get credentialsMap by cmd
19:27:39.169 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate.RunnerOptions - found system property 'karate.options': --tags ~@ignore
after all
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.875 s <<< FAILURE! - in examples.MainRunner
[ERROR] testAll  Time elapsed: 0.872 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/ScriptObjectMirror
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror
```

I tried to run next and it's working:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
        ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
        engine.eval("print('Hello World!');");
    }
```

What's wrong?
env:

```
Intellij Idea 2019.3
Bundled (Maven 3) version 3.6.1

java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)
```

thanks for your answers!

Comment: I want to debug through a karate testing project using Maven, because if I have some problems on CI with running karate tests through Maven, I can run and debug using the same env and parameters on my local machine

Answer (score 1):

Just use the Visual Studio Code extension / Karate Runner: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/IDE-Support#vs-code-karate-plugin

Video here: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1167533484560142336